# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" in nw.js window opened using nw.Window.open()

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js, nwjs

I feel like I am missing something simple.

I'm developing a "tray" application in nw.js. To do this I set `"main"` to a `"main.js"` file in my `package.json`. In `main.js` I instantiate a `Tray` object and call `nw.Window.open('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))` on the click event of the tray object.

It's all working fine, except I am not able to use `require` in any scripts inside `index.html`. I get an error saying:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Note that if I set `"main"` to `"index.html"` in the `package.json`, everything works fine. The problem only shows up when open `index.html` using `nw.Window.open('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))`.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the `node-remote` option in `package.json`, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

`nw.Window.open('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))`

with

`nw.Window.open('index.html')`

did the trick.